# How can I show that $\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(G^\dagger G)\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(G G^\dagger)\right)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, trace

I'm slightly stuck on the following question:

> Prove that: $\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(G^\dagger G)\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(G G^\dagger)\right)$ where $G$ is any operator.

Using the definition of the trace and definition $B = G^{\dagger} G$ and $C = GG^{\dagger}$, I have the expressions:

$$\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(G^\dagger G)\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(B)\right)=\sum_jf(b_j)$$
and
$$\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(GG^\dagger)\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left( f(C)\right)=\sum_jf(c_j),$$
where $b_j$ and $c_j$ are the eignevalues of $B$ and $C$, which are hermitian. I have taken the trace w.r.t to the same basis which spans the Hilbert Space: $\sum_{j} \cdots = 1 $.

I'm unable to show how and why must the traces be equal.

Comment: notice the following property of the trace of two matrices, $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$.

Comment: You define $B=G^\dagger G$ and $C=G G^\dagger$. With your definition of the trace and the use of the spectral theorem you are almost there: How are the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$ related?

Comment: It is not true for general $f$, e.g. for $f(A) = v^\dagger Aw$ and given $v,w$ it is not true (or in a fixed basis $f(A) = A_{11}$).

Comment: @doetoe  I think OP means any $f$ expandable in a Taylor series, so only using powers of $A$.

Comment: @knzhou yes probably

Comment: @schmui what's the relation you're hinting at? The operators B and C don't form a CSCO, right?

Answer (score 4):

This follows from the cyclicity of the trace, i.e. the property that
$$\mathrm{Tr}(AB)=\mathrm{Tr}(BA),$$
which extends to the cyclic permutation $\mathrm{Tr}(ABC\cdots XYZ)=\mathrm{Tr}(BC\cdots XYZA)$ for larger products. Thus, if you expand $f$ in its Taylor series, you get
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Tr}\left(f(G^\dagger G)\right)
& =
\mathrm{Tr}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(G^\dagger G)^n\right)
\\& =
\mathrm{Tr}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}G^\dagger G\cdots G^\dagger G\right)
\\& =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\mathrm{Tr}\left(G^\dagger G\cdots G^\dagger G\right)
\\& =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\mathrm{Tr}\left(GG^\dagger \cdots G^\dagger GG^\dagger \right)
\\& =
\mathrm{Tr}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}GG^\dagger \cdots G^\dagger GG^\dagger \right)
\\& =
\mathrm{Tr}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(G G^\dagger)^n\right)
\\& =
\mathrm{Tr}\left(f(GG^\dagger )\right)
.
\end{align}

Alternatively, you can calculate the trace via the eigenvalues of $B=G^\dagger G$ and $C=GG^\dagger$, in which case you need to relate the two sets of eigenvalues; this can be done by noting that if $B\psi=b\psi$ gives an eigenpair of $B$, then
$$C(G\psi)=GG^\dagger G\psi=GB\psi=Gb\psi=b(G\psi)$$
also gives an eigenpair with the same eigenvalue. (In infinite dimensions, of course, this argument needs to be handled carefully, in case $\psi$ is normalized but $G\psi$ is not as well-behaved, but you're assuming loads in just getting to the point-spectrum sum you use in the first place.)

These are probably the two main ideas behind most proofs of that fact - the rest of the details revolve around what properties $G$ is known to have, and how you're defining $f$ at an operator in the first place.

Comment: That's interesting. I expressed the function as function applied to the eigenvalues of the operator, and I then expressed the new operator in the basis in which the operator was initially diagonal. I couldn't seem to draw the conclusion from that construct, although I could visualize it with matrices being multiplied and all.

Comment: Yeah, the relationship between $G^\dagger G$ and $GG^\dagger$ is not obvious, but it is very fundamental for many fields. If I find a clear example I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

$G^\dagger G$ and $G G^\dagger$ are unitary equivalent in the finite dimensional case :

There exists the polar decomposition $G = R U$ where $R \geq 0$ and $U$ unitary.
Then $G^\dagger G = U^\dagger R^2 U = U^\dagger (G G^\dagger) U$.

But from this it follows that $G^\dagger G$ and $G G^\dagger$ have the same eigenvalues.

In the infinite dimensional case we know only that U is a partial isometry .